# how to get smallest string from big string (concat from small string)

Tags: javascript

how to find the smallest string from a string . in other words find the smallest string such that it can be concatenated some number of times to obtain big string.

Input `rbrb` output `rb` (my function is working fine)

Another example

Input `bcdbcdbcdbcd` output :`bcd` (my function working fine)

I tried like this.

```
function getSmallestString(s){
  
  let i= 0;
  let tem = '';
 
  
  while(true){
     let mid = s.length/2;
    let tem = s.substring(0,mid);
    if(tem + tem == s){
      s= tem
    }else {
      return s;
    }
    
  }
  
}

console.log('bcdbcdbcdbcd')
```

https://jsbin.com/liracurala/1/edit?html,js,output

here my case fail

```
function getSmallestString(s){
  
  let i= 0;
  let tem = '';
 
  
  while(true){
     let mid = Math.floor(s.length/2);
    let tem = s.substring(0,mid);
    if(tem + tem == s){
      s= tem
    }else {
      return s;
    }
    
  }
  
}

console.log(getSmallestString('ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo'))
```

Expected output is `o`

**Each answer fail in this case `lrbb`**  expected output `lrbb`

Comment: I updated my answer, it should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, your task was to find the smallest sequence of characters from a string that could be duplicated to replicate the original string.

`wordIsDivisibleBy` does that job.

```js
function wordIsDivisibleBy(word) {
    
    for (let distance = 1; distance <= (word.length / 2) ; distance++) { 
      if (Number.isInteger(word.length / distance)) {
        let sequence = word.slice(0, distance);
        let numToRepeat = word.length / distance;
        if (sequence.repeat(numToRepeat) === word) {
            console.log(sequence);
            return;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(word)
}
  
wordIsDivisibleBy("a");
wordIsDivisibleBy("aa");
wordIsDivisibleBy("ab");
wordIsDivisibleBy("aaa");
wordIsDivisibleBy("aab");
wordIsDivisibleBy("abbabbabb");
wordIsDivisibleBy("abbabbabx");
```

**How it works**

This function takes a chunk of the word (always starting from the beginning of the word). We call this chunk `sequence`. The function asks if every same-sized adjacent chunk is the same as `sequence`. `sequence`'s length starts off at 1 character and increases at each iteration of the main `for loop` - but not before `sequence` would reach over half the size of the original word. The first `sequence` that passes the test is our answer. If no `sequence` passes the test, the original `word` is logged out.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getSmallestString(str) {
    var current = "";
    for(var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; ++i) {
        current += str[i];
        if(str.replace(new RegExp(current,"g"),"") == "") return current
    }
}
```

Comment: it fail in `lrbb` this case

Comment: It fail in `abaca` or in `aabbbaaa`

Answer (score 1):

Let m be the size of the smaller substring. To improve the time complexity you can use the fact that the substring size possible would be of the size of the divisors of m. So, the time complexity becomes O(N*sqrt(N)). Here is the code for it -

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define int long long int

int findSmallestDivisor(string s, string t){
    int n = s.size();
    int m = t.size();
    if(n%m != 0)
        return -1;
    string temp="";
    int val = n/m;
    for(int i=0;i<val;i++)
        temp += t;
    if(temp != s)
        return -1;
    vector<int> V;
    for(int i=1;i<=sqrt(m);i++){
        if(m%i == 0){
            V.push_back(i);
            if(i != m/i)
                V.push_back(m/i);
        }
    }
    int res = -1;
    sort(V.begin(), V.end());
    for(auto x: V){
        string temp = "";
        string temp1 = t.substr(0,x);
        val = m/x;
        for(int j=0;j<val;j++)
            temp += temp1;
        if(temp == t){
            res = x;
            break;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int32_t main(){
    string S, T;
    cin>>S>>T;
    cout<<findSmallestDivisor(S,T);

    return 0;
}
```

For improving time complexity you can think of a solution in a different way. The possible substring length will be the LCM of the difference of consecutive position for each character.
For example -

```
t = "bcdbcd"
position of 'b' - 0, 3 - Lcm of difference of consecutive position is 3
position of 'c' - 1, 4 - Lcm of difference of consecutive position is 3
position of 'd' - 2, 5 - Lcm of difference of consecutive position is 3
So, LCM of all the position difference is also 3 in this case.
```

This makes the program run very fast.
In the worst case the code will run in O(k*N) where k will be some small constant factor. A rigorous TC analysis is required. I just tried to make the code as faster as I could. Here is my code -

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define int long long int

int findSmallestDivisor(string s, string t){
    int n = s.size();
    int m = t.size();
    if(n%m != 0)
        return -1;
    string temp="";
    int val = n/m;
    for(int i=0;i<val;i++)
        temp += t;
    if(temp != s)
        return -1;
    int res = -1;
    vector<int> V[26];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        V[t[i]-'a'].push_back(i);
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        if(V[i].size() == 1)
            res = m;
    }
    if(res != -1)
        return m;
    int index;
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        if(V[i].size() >= 2)
            index = i;
    }
    val = V[index][1]-V[index][0];
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<V[i].size();j++){
            int temp1 = V[i][j]-V[i][j-1];
            int gcd = __gcd(val, temp1);
            val = (temp1*val)/gcd;
            if(val > m)
                break;
        }
        if(val > m)
            break;
    }
    if(val > m)
        return m;
    int x = val;
    while(x <= m){
        temp = "";
        string temp1 = t.substr(0,x);
        val = m/x;
        for(int j=0;j<val;j++)
            temp += temp1;
        if(temp == t){
            res = x;
            break;
        }
        x += val;
    }

    return res;
}

int32_t main(){
    string S, T;
    cin>>S>>T;
    cout<<findSmallestDivisor(S,T);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check gradually

I hope I have found the right solution for you :)

I use `str.repeat()` to create a repeat to check with the string.

```
function findSmallestStringRepeat(string) {
  let myMatchStr = string;
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length - 1; i++) {
    myMatchStr = string.substr(0, i + 1);
    const compareString = myMatchStr.repeat(Math.ceil(string.length / myMatchStr.length));
    if (string === compareString.substr(0, string.length)) return myMatchStr;
  }
  return string; // There are no repeats in string to get smaller string
}
```

And add snippet with checks:

```js
function findSmallestStringRepeat(string) {
  let myMatchStr = string;
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length - 1; i++) {
    myMatchStr = string.substr(0, i + 1);
    const compareString = myMatchStr.repeat(Math.ceil(string.length / myMatchStr.length));
    if (string === compareString.substr(0, string.length)) return myMatchStr;
  }
  return string; // There are no repeats in string to get smaller string
}

const string1 = "lrbb";
const string2 = "bb";
const string3 = "abab";
const string4 = "abaca";
const string5 = "abcdefghi";
const string6 = "abcabcabc";
const string7 = "aabbbaaa";

console.log('For String:', string1 ,' - We get:', findSmallestStringRepeat(string1));
console.log('For String:', string2 ,' - We get:', findSmallestStringRepeat(string2));
console.log('For String:', string3 ,' - We get:', findSmallestStringRepeat(string3));
console.log('For String:', string4 ,' - We get:', findSmallestStringRepeat(string4));
console.log('For String:', string5 ,' - We get:', findSmallestStringRepeat(string5));
console.log('For String:', string6 ,' - We get:', findSmallestStringRepeat(string6));
console.log('For String:', string7 ,' - We get:', findSmallestStringRepeat(string7));
```

Comment: Might be wrong but I think OP was first trying to find if stringA could consist of a smaller string such that if you repeat that smaller string a certain number of times, it would eventually be identical to string A.